# OpenSSL error preventing Apache2.2 startup on win32

Tags: winapi, apache2, openssl, mod-ssl

So I go to start my Apache2.2 service, which uses mod_ssl, from the command line with "-k start -e debug".  It shows all the modules loading, waits a second or two, then returns me to the command prompt without error.  The service, however, is no longer running.  In the error log, there's this text:

```
Starting the Apache2.2-ssl service
The Apache2.2-ssl service is running.
zed OpenSSL library
```

That last line is not written to the log if I take off the "-e debug", and also returns zero hits on Google when quoted.

In the Event Viewer app log, there's this:

> Faulting application httpd.exe,
>   version 2.2.13.0, faulting module
>   ssleay32.dll, version 0.9.8.11, fault
>   address 0x0001a177.

This is on Windows Server 2003 Standard SP2.  Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was configuration related.  I had been LoadModule-ing mod_ssl in a "push @PerlConfig" in a <Perl> section.  While this works for other modules--auth_digest, authn_file, and authz_user among them--apparently it doesn't for mod_ssl.

In fact, trying to LoadModule in such a section also causes trouble on CentOS 6.4.  On startup you'll get a `2717 Segmentation fault` error.

Comment: This is not the only thing that apparently cannot go inside a `<Perl>` section: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=106068